# swift Generate shared key using ECDH

Tags: ios, swift, curve, crypt, ecdh

I am trying to encrypt a message to the server.
To do this, I generate a public and private key.
I send my public key to the server and receive its public key from it.

```
func generatePair() {
    if let crypto = GMEllipticCurveCrypto.generateKeyPair(for: GMEllipticCurveSecp256r1) {
        crypto.compressedPublicKey = false
        curveCrypto = crypto
        if let publicKey = crypto.publicKey {
            let pub = Data(publicKey[1...publicKey.count-1])
            self.publicKey = pub.base64EncodedString()
            self.privateKey = crypto.privateKeyBase64
        }
    }
}
```

Upon receipt, I try to generate a shared key to encrypt the data.

```
func generateSecret(withKey key: String) {
    guard let crypto = curveCrypto else {
        return
    }
    print("generateSecret \(key)")
    sharedKey = crypto.sharedSecret(forPublicKeyBase64: key)
}
```

But I get the error in line (sharedKey = crypto.sharedSecret(forPublicKeyBase64: key))

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Invalid Key', reason: 'Public key {length = 64, bytes = 0xace3000d e1483ed9 82d88432 9397c716 ... d64e0fe1 47920d9f } is invalid'

My public key and server key are the same length.

What is I doing wrong?

Comment: Would you be open to a solution using a better library?

Comment: I will give you an advice - never use old unmaintained libraries for crypto. That library haven't been touched in 7 years.  Nowadays, every iOS devices has those functions natively (for about 5 years now). Use what the system gives you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found the solution.

After receiving public key from server I should do this:

```
private func getPublicKey(publicKey: String) -> String? {
    if let publicKeyData = Data(base64Encoded: publicKey) {
        var newKeyData = publicKeyData
        newKeyData.insert(0x04, at: 0)
        if let compressKeyData = curveCrypto?.compressPublicKey(newKeyData) {
            return compressKeyData.base64EncodedString()
        } else {
            print("PUB KEY ERROR: compressKeyData")
            return nil
        }
    } else {
        print("PUB KEY ERROR: b64")
        return nil
    }
}
```

And this public key should be used for generation shared key.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are using [GMEllipticCurveCrypto](https://github.com/ricmoo/GMEllipticCurveCrypto) by ricmoo.

This framework use compressed keys internally. Which is why it will always fail as the length of the input key(65) doesn't match the expected length of compressed key(33).

Note that the function `sharedSecret(forPublicKeyBase64:)` will call `sharedSecret(forPublicKey:)` internally. So the final solution is to compress the key again before passing it to `sharedSecret(forPublicKey:)`. You can choose to expose `compressPublicKey` function in header file or use update the function in .m file with the solution below.

#### Original:

```
// Prepare the public key
- (NSData*)sharedSecretForPublicKey: (NSData*)otherPublicKey {
    [...]
    uint8_t l_other_public[_bytes + 1];
    if ([otherPublicKey length] != _bytes + 1) {
        [NSException raise:@"Invalid Key" format:@"Public key %@ is invalid", otherPublicKey];
    }
    [...]
}
```

#### Fix:

```
- (NSData*)sharedSecretForPublicKey: (NSData*)otherPublicKey {
    NSData* compressedKey = [self compressPublicKey:otherPublicKey];
    [...]
    // Prepare the public key
    uint8_t l_other_public[_bytes + 1];
    if ([compressedKey length] != _bytes + 1) {
        [NSException raise:@"Invalid Key" format:@"Public key %@ is invalid", compressedKey];
    }
    [compressedKey getBytes:&l_other_public length:[compressedKey length]];
    [...]
}
```

Comment: Could you type with code in swift?) I wanna try this solution

Comment: What do you mean by rewrite this code in swift? The fix is not for your code but for the library that you copy from ricmoo repo. You should replace in function `sharedSecretForPublicKey` from line 1517 to 1522 in file `GMEllipticCurveCrypto.m` with the fix(between the [...]) and also put the `NSData* compressedKey = [self compressPublicKey:otherPublicKey];` at the beginning of that function

Comment: I have a error
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Invalid Key', reason: 'Public key (null) is invalid'

Inside this code line
[NSException raise:@"Invalid Key" format:@"Public key %@ is invalid", compressedKey];

compressedKey = nil